# Flutter can't find ANDROID_HOME path

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, ubuntu

I am having troubles getting flutter to detect the ANDROID_HOME in ~/.bashrc

I get this error when I `flutter doctor`:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ ANDROID_HOME = /usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
      but Android SDK not found at this location.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
```

I cd into ANDROID_HOME using `ls $ANDROID_HOME`, then `ls -la` gave me:

```
i992@paschal:/usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin$ ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 14:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Aug 24 14:55 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5322 Aug 24 14:55 apkanalyzer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5313 Aug 24 14:55 avdmanager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5281 Aug 24 14:55 lint
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5310 Aug 24 14:55 screenshot2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5320 Aug 24 14:55 sdkmanager
```

This confirms that sdkmanager is present. Any idea why flutter isn't picking it up?

~/.bashrc path conf:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was later able to fix this; I found that the problem can be fixed by running;

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28" "build-tools;28.0.3"
```

Once this is done, open bashrc set the ANDROID_HOME to:

```
ANDROID_HOME = /usr/lib/android-sdk
```

then run `source ~/.bashrc` to update bash. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the SDK location to environment variables. I was getting the same error but then adding the following paths to environment variables worked for me.

1. D:\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin
2. D:\Sdk\platform-tools